# Can someone explain to me what a contingent fact is?

Tags: epistemology, belief, contingent

English is not my first language and I'm trying to understand Williams Argument in "Deciding to believe" when he says that it is not possibe to bring about belief at will and that this is not a contingent fact. So what is a contingent fact?

Comment: A fact is a fact: "the rose is red" is a statement expressing a fact. "Contingent" means that it can happen or not. A rose can be either red or pink; thus, the fact that this rose is red can be said that is contingent. 1+1=2 is a mathematical fact that is necessary and not contingent.

Comment: Omg thank you so much that was so helpful! Now I get it

Comment: Answers should go in the box following where it says "Your Answer"

Comment: "Contingent" means that there is no _necessity_ to the fact.

Comment: Maybe I can explain it, and maybe I can't.

Comment: Williams probably means that there is something in the very nature of beliefs that makes it impossible to bring them about at will. In other words, it is not impossible by some accidental happenstance. If it was, it would still be a fact, but only a contingent fact.

Answer (score 2):

Contingency is primarily about an attempt by philosophers to codify the intuitions we have about certain sorts of facts. Some facts seem like they could have been otherwise. For example, a meteor hit the earth and wiped out the dinosaurs, but it could have been otherwise. The dinosaurs could have continued to exist and higher mammals might never have evolved. I was in a car accident and was injured, but it could have been otherwise. The other car might not even have been there.

Facts like this, where it could have been otherwise, are called contingent. Aren't all facts like that? No, there are facts like 1+3=4 that don't seem to have that characteristic. There is no way that 1+3 could have been something else. Or there is the fact that if a man is a bachelor, he is unmarried. There is no way that he could be married and be a bachelor. Facts like this are called non-contingent.

Typically, you see the words "necessary" and "possible" used in this context. A necessary proposition is one that is non-contingently true. A possible proposition is one that is not non-contingently false.

Propositions that are contingent are generally facts about the material world, empirical propositions. Propositions that are non-contingent are generally facts about meaning (like what "bachelor" means) or about logic or mathematics. There are other, less obvious categories of propositions that are said to be non-contingent. For example, some philosophers say that water is necessarily H2O and that George Bush's father was necessarily George H. W. Bush (otherwise, he wouldn't be George Bush).

Some philosophers say that God's existence is non-contingent: if he exists, he exists necessarily. The reason for this is that contingent facts stands in need of explanations. Why did the meteor hit the earth? There was some course of physical events that led to that event, some series of events that explains that event, but God (if he exists) is not created and pre-exists anything that could explain him. Since nothing can explain why God exists, he must exist necessarily or must necessarily fail to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Considering, of course, that the expression "nothing can explain why" is based on the access to an infinite knowledge of the past, the present, and the future. That said, I would quote an example what would illustrate the previous statement with a possible comparison... "Einstein’s 1915 general theory of relativity, for example, was based on theoretical mathematics developed 50 years earlier by the great German mathematician Bernhard Riemann that did not have any known practical applications at the time of its intellectual creation" (“Arguments why God (very probably) exists” Published: May 10, 2017 9.04pm EDT Updated: May 14, 2017 7.47am EDT).  As I understand it, "all-knowing" is one of the attributes of God. This is a perfect place to leap from Philosophy to Theology unless we qualify the expression "nothing can explain why" to "we do not know yet why God exists".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/57404)